# With C# devkit, how do I access the ItemId, UnitPrice, and Qty of an Invoice Line

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to insert new invoice lines into QB using the standard AnyWhere C# SDK.
But when I try the below, ItemId, UnitPrice, and Qty are not defined (not elements of the object InvoiceLine).

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.InvoiceLine  InvLine  = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.InvoiceLine();

InvLine.ItemId     =     17;
InvLine.Desc       = "DEMO";
Invline.UnitPrice  = 100.00;
InvLine.Qty        =      4;
InvLine.Amount     = 400.00;
...    
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Invoice  results_set = commonService.Add(Invoice);
```

I saw the other very similar post, but I seem to have the reverse problem.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong (are they present under a different name maybe)?
(Be gentle - I am a two day newbie) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some attributes are set through the Items/ItemsElementName properties.

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.InvoiceLine  InvLine  = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.InvoiceLine();
InvLine.Desc = "DEMO";
InvLine.Amount = 400.0m;
InvLine.AmountSpecified = true;
InvLine.ItemsElementName = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemsChoiceType2[]
                                {
                                    Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemsChoiceType2.ItemId,
                                    Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemsChoiceType2.Qty,
                                    Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemsChoiceType2.UnitPrice
                                };
InvLine.Items = new object[]
                    {
                        new IdType(){idDomain=idDomainEnum.QB, Value="17"},
                        4m,
                        100m
                    };
```

It has nothing to do with you being a newbie.  The DevKits are built directly from the IDS service schemas and have this limitation as a result.  If you are like me and jump right into coding, it's not easy to figure out.

Here is my PasteBin with some more examples:  http://pastebin.com/u/IDNPeterL

Comment: WOW - THANK YOU SO MUCH, yea, would have never guessed that one.